# How do I deploy files to data directory for Apache Cordova application

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, cordova-plugin-file

I'm looking to include some files in the data directory as part of my applicaiton. I'm using Visual Studio to create the applicaiton.

How do I include files to be deployed to the data directory? Do I create a certain folder in my project? Do I need to mark them as content?

Kind Regards

Comment: Deploy in the sense, you gotta dump some content in the data directory?

Comment: Yeah, when I create my apk/windows equivilent etc, it needs to drop files into the data directory

Comment: Any reason not to create a data directory in your www directory and put your files there?

Comment: Mainly because I have been having issues accessing files from the filesystem on windows in the applicationDirectory. I think I have resolved these issues though, so this may now be redundant.

Comment: @Andrew you may check out this link to get an idea about file operations in Cordova - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Answer (score 1):

You could write some code that copies your desired files at runtime from the read-only `www/` directory to a read-write directory. I have found a [blog post](https://pouchdb.com/2016/04/28/prebuilt-databases-with-pouchdb.html) that exactly describes this:

```
// copy a database file from www/ in the app directory to the data directory
function copyDatabaseFile(dbName) {
  var sourceFileName = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/' + dbName;
  var targetDirName = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
  // resolve the source and target filenames simultaneously
  return Promise.all([
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      resolveLocalFileSystemURL(sourceFileName, resolve, reject);
    }),
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      resolveLocalFileSystemURL(targetDirName, resolve, reject);
    })
  ]).then(function (files) {
    var sourceFile = files[0];
    var targetDir = files[1];
    // try to fetch the target file, to check if it exists
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      targetDir.getFile(dbName, {}, resolve, reject);
    }).catch(function () {
      // target file doesn't exist already, so copy it
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        sourceFile.copyTo(targetDir, dbName, resolve, reject);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

You could invoke a similar function within your apps entrypoint after cordova emitted the [`deviceready`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html) event.